# Type of object in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I got a code which briefly as follows
First they define a struct in a class:

```
Struct Energy{
double elas;
double slip;
double dash;
}
```

.
.
.
Then they define an object of this struct

```
Energy* Prop;
```

.
.
.
Then they use it to write a condition as below

```
if (!Prop){
Prop->elas = elas_;
Prop->slip = slip_;
Prop->dash = dash_;
}
```

What makes me confuse is as I know the type of Prop is Energy. So how they can use it in an if condition. I am new in C++, so many things I don't understand. Hope you guys help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: You need to spend at least a week on reading a good [C++ programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) book and you should focus on C++11 or better. See also [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). We cannot teach you C++ in a few minutes.

Comment: The code is wrong and buggy ([undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)) unless you replace `if (!Prop)` by `if (Prop != nullptr)` or just `if (Prop)`

Comment: Yeah, I only copy a part of code which I thought related to my question. Of course, I need to learn more. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @Basile: could you recommend me one or two books? Thank you

Comment: I already did thru the [first](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) link I have you....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the star that comes after Energy in the variable declaration,

```
Energy* Prop;
```

That means Prop is of type Energy*, meaning it is a pointer to an Energy type. Pointers can point to an instance (valid or not, but it's not the scope of this question) or to nothing, also called null.

When used in conditions, pointers work like pretty much an integer value, if it's zero (or null) it will be false, otherwise true.

Writing `if (!prop)` checks if the pointer is null.

```
if (!prop) {
    // prop is null, handle error
}
else {
    // prop points to something, you can use it
}
```

Edit: Though if you're using C++11 or later take a look at `nullptr`.

Comment: Wouldn't `if (!prop)` check if the pointer *is* null? ('Not nonzero'?)

Comment: My mistake, you're correct. Which means the code in the the OP's answer is not correct either.

Answer (score 1):

Prop is a *pointer* to an Energy struct, which means it can be null (point at nothing). Pointers are true if they are not null.

Comment: Thank Wander, the Prop is supposed to be False so !Prop can be True for the expression to excute. So if they define the Prop like this and didn't assign anything, Prop could be null (which means False). Is it correct?

Comment: If they didn't assign something Prop could be literally anything. But yes, it could be null. Read up on pointers, you'll use them a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!Prop)` means `if (Prop != 0)` or `if (Prop != nullptr)`

Comment: or better `if (Prop != nullptr)`

Comment: It could have two meanings? I just thought if condition need true or false. So !Prop should be true or false as your second option